# Python plot update on text input

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I would like to create a plot with a function whose parameters can be updated by a text input on the figure in allocated textboxes. Let's say it would look something like the following:
[image]

Here you input your values for a, b, c, and d and then press on the Update button to update the plot with those given parameters. Currently, I have the following, but I don't know how to connect the matplotlib.widgets.TextBox and an update button to the plot axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

def function(x, a, b, c, d):
     y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d
     return y

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = function(x, 2, 2, 2, 2) # Initial values for a, b, c, and d

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(6, 5, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, 0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, 1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, 2])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, 3])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, 4])

ax1.plot(x,y)
```

I'm not sure how to make the textboxes and the update button. I have been using https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/textbox.html as reference, but without prevail.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You could simply utilize the fact that changing a text box or pressing enter causes the "submit" callback to be called, so you don't have to have a button there.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a very basic example, this doesn't rescale the axes to conform with the new function, but the functionality you want works.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox, Button
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

def function(x, a, b, c, d):
     y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d
     return y

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = function(x, 2, 2, 2, 2) # Initial values for a, b, c, and d

#fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gs = GridSpec(6, 5, figure=fig)

axbox_text = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.5, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox_text, "Some title")

axbox_button = fig.add_axes([0.65, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
button = Button(axbox_button, "Hello")

def submit(expression):
    print(f"Pressed somewhere {expression}")
    if expression.inaxes == axbox_button: # Make sure the button was pressed
        print(f"Pressed button, value is {text_box.text}")
        ax.lines.clear()
        y = function(x, float(text_box.text), 2, 2, 2)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        

text_box.disconnect(text_box.disconnect_events) # Disconnect all other events
text_box.connect_event('button_press_event', submit) # Connect the button event

ax.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```